# Waking up Stm32F4 from sleep mode on button press

Tags: stm32f4

I am putting my board using `STM32F4` into sleep mode. I want to wake up when I press button. I am using following code for implementing this

```
void SleepMode(void)
{
  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct;
  MX_GPIO_Deinit();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOC_CLK_ENABLE();
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = B1_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_IT_RISING;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(B1_GPIO_Port, &GPIO_InitStruct);
  HAL_UART_DeInit(&huart4);
  HAL_SuspendTick();
  __HAL_RCC_PWR_CLK_ENABLE();
  HAL_PWR_EnterSLEEPMode(0, PWR_SLEEPENTRY_WFI);
}
```

The board goes into sleep mode but doesn't wake up when I press button. Where I am making mistake in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you configured the EXTI line in NVIC to start EXTI ISR on the button press? You may also need to resume SysTick when the device wakes up by calling `HAL_ResumeTick()`